# spring-boot project and utility library written using spring-boot with different versions of spring-boot project

Tags: spring-boot

Suppose I've created spring boot project with version 2.3.5.RELEASE(Project_1) and other user utility library using spring-boot version 2.3.0.RELEASE(Project_2).

if I Project_2 as dependency in Project_1, will it cause any issues as both project uses different versions of spring-boot?

Comment: well, does the library have a hard dependency on version-specific spring boot functionality? if yes, then sure, it will cause an issue.

Comment: Yes, library is developed and maintained by other team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the library has a hard dependency on version-specific spring boot functionality, then sure, it will cause an issue. Just like with any dependency.